# java.lang.IllegalStateException: OverrideDeadline required. Given: -2127623

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-play-services, google-apps, android-jobscheduler

This is how I found this error:

1. UUT flash 01-10-09.00-OG-U00-STD
2. Set the current date and time on UUT.
3. Connect UUT to WLAN network.
4. Tap play store and try to setup google account.

Stack trace:

> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: Process:
>   com.android.vending, PID: 9274
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application
>   com.google.android.finsky.application.impl.FinskyApplication:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: OverrideDeadline required. Given:
>   -2127623
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5768)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1669)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6528)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: OverrideDeadline required. Given:
>   -2127623
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   com.google.android.finsky.scheduler.b.b.b(SourceFile:60)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   com.google.android.finsky.scheduler.b.b.a(SourceFile:41)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   com.google.android.finsky.hygiene.impl.d.d(SourceFile:39)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   com.google.android.finsky.application.impl.c.b(SourceFile:327)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   com.google.android.finsky.application.impl.FinskyApplication.onCreate(SourceFile:8)
>
> 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
>
> > 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5765)
> >
> > 08-21 12:37:31.426  9274  9274 E AndroidRuntime: ... 8 more

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.